# Flutter Just Audio: question about java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, just-audio

I have the same issue as mentionned here:

https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/442

But in my dart/Flutter audiobook app. Anyone knows how to handle it in Dart?

Thanks!
Michal